# Get JSON from Google Apps Script URL via Erlang

Tags: google-apps-script, erlang

Good Evening!

I've been looking into the possibility of using GAS(Google Apps Script) to host a small bit of javascript that lets me use the new Google finance apps api. The intention being that I'll be using the stock information for a project which involves the use of stock data. I know that there are a few ways to get stock information from Google, but the data that the finanace app returns is more in-line with other sources we are using. (One constraint on this project is that we have multiple sources).

I've written the javascript and I can call a httpc:request to the URL for the script given to me from Google. In the browser the JS returns the json object as I want it, however when the call is made from Erlang I'm getting it in a list of ascii. From checking the values it appears to be a document starting like:

Below is the javascript and the url to see the json:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzEvuuQl4jkrbPCz7hf9Zv4nvIOzqAkBxL1ixslLBxmSEhksQM/exec

```js
function doGet() {
  var stock = FinanceApp.getStockInfo('LON:TSCO');

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(stock))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

For the erlang, it's a simple request but I've not been doing erlang long, so perhaps I've messed something up here (The URL being the one mentioned above). I've got crypto / ssl / inets when I'm testing this on the command line.

```
 {ok, {Version, Headers, Body}} = httpc:request(get, URL, []}, [], []).
```

I think it's also worth mentioning that when i curl it from Cygwin, I get a massive load of HTML also, I've included it below, but if you see it you'll thank me for not posting it in here! http://pastebin.com/UtJHXjRm

I've been updating the script as I go with the new versions but I'm at a bit of a loss as to why it's not returning correctly.

If anyone can give me any pointers I'd be very grateful! I get the feeling that it's not intended to be used this way, perhaps only within other Google products and such.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be necessary to review how are you deploying the Web App, specifically the **Who has access to the app**, to access without authentication should be configured as shown in the image:

[image]

See [Deploying Your Script as a Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#deploying) from the documentation.

In my test, by running:

```
curl -L https://script.google.com/macros/s/************/exec
```

Get the following result:

```js
{
  "priceopen":358,
  "change":2.199981689453125,
  "high52":388.04998779296875,
  "tradetime":"2013-10-11T15:35:18.000Z",
  "currency":"GBX",
  "timezone":"Europe/London",
  "low52":307,
  "quote":357.8999938964844,
  "name":"Tesco PLC",
  "exchange":"LON",
  "marketcap":28929273763,
  "symbol":"TSCO",
  "volumedelay":0,
  "shares":8083060703,
  "pe":23.4719295501709,
  "eps":0.15248000621795654,
  "price":357.8999938964844,
  "has_stock_data":true,
  "volumeavg":14196534,
  "volume":8885809,
  "changepct":0.6184935569763184,
  "high":359.5,
  "datadelay":0,
  "low":355.8999938964844,
  "closeyest":355.70001220703125
}
```

Comment: the key is to publish the apps script anonymously (which it currently is not) or to deal with Oauth2 . Using the script through a browser works if logged on to google or results in html request for login to G-Account.

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thanks very much! (I was %100 sure I had set that up to be anonymous, I think I'd forgotten to save the newest version!)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your GET is not following the REDIRECT  that happens when you use contentService. Look at the html returned there is a redirect in there.